# Intersection of 2 arrays and doing operation on each

Tags: swift, algorithm, collections

The code below successfully take a list of favourites names and matches it to a smaller list of names, and upon each match or mismatch, it creates a new data struct indicating if it was favourited.   (However this seem to be (N^2) complexity)

```
listOfNames.forEach {
    var faved = false
    if namesFavorited.contains($0) {
        faved = true
    }
    let model = DetailNameModel(name: $0, favorited: faved)
    detailNameModelArray.append(model)
}
```

Is there a better way to do this that can SCALE to 10s of thousands say down to N or NLogN?

Comment: You can change `namesFavorited` to some kind of tree. Searching would become O(log(n)), so the whole thing would be `O(nlog(n))`. See this [cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com) I also suggest not using `listOfNames` and `namesFavorited` if your can. Deal with `DetailNameModel` objects in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set` collection. It provides efficient ways to interact with collections. More detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set).

**Updated code:**

```
let listOfNames: Set = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5", "name6", "name7", "name8"]
let namesFavorited: Set = ["name2", "name3", "name5", "name6", "name8", "name9", "name10", "name11"]

let nonFav = listOfNames.subtracting(namesFavorited) // O(m*n)
let fav = listOfNames.intersection(namesFavorited) // O(m*n)

var detailNameModelArray: [DetailNameModel] = []

let nonFavDetailNames = nonFav.map { // O(nonFav.count)
    DetailNameModel(name: $0, favorited: false)
}
detailNameModelArray.append(contentsOf: nonFavDetailNames)

let favDetailNames = fav.map { // O(fav.count)
    DetailNameModel(name: $0, favorited: true)
}
detailNameModelArray.append(contentsOf: favDetailNames)

print(detailNameModelArray) // O(fav.count)
```

You can generate a lot of data and compare my method and yours. I think my method will win.

Comment: Doing an intersect then doing a map is good idea.  However I think both of our complexity is O(m*n) .

Comment: @mskw Yes. I tested both solutions and my faster. However I don't know why

Comment: Looks like internal optimization of the intersect with Map is faster than a forEach loop with contains.